# Constructing a insert query based on a LINQ query

Tags: c#

I am trying to build a sql insert query based on the number of filled out textboxes returned from a `LINQ` query. Basically, the start of the textboxes start at the tab index number 13 and ends at the tab index number 33 and adds the non empty textboxes to a `keyvaluepair` list. The issue that I am confused about is how to add the filled out textboxes' values to named parameters inside the insert query without having a error of `number of query values and destination fields are not the same`. Here is the code I have in place:

```
 // use LINQ to fetch all the children textboxes based on the ones that are not empty
 System.Collections.Generic.Dictionary<string, string> dictionary = tabCtrl1.TabPages["tabPage1"].Controls.OfType<TextBox>()
    .Where(t => t.TabIndex >= startTabIndex && t.TabIndex <= endTabIndex && !string.IsNullOrWhiteSpace(t.Text))
    .Select(x => new System.Collections.Generic.KeyValuePair<string, string>(x.Name, x.Text))
    .ToDictionary(z => z.Key, z => z.Value);

 // loop through all the children textboxes
 // and assign them to the list members.childTextBoxes
 foreach (System.Collections.Generic.KeyValuePair<string, string> kvp in dictionary)
 {
     members.childTextBoxes.Add(new System.Collections.Generic.KeyValuePair<string, string>($"{kvp.Key}", $"{kvp.Value}"));
 }
```

and then constructing of the insert query:

```
 for (int i = 0; i < members.childTextBoxes.Count; i++)
 {
     using (members.DBCommand = new System.Data.OleDb.OleDbCommand("INSERT INTO children (pid, childName, birthday, childEmail)" +
         "VALUES (" + lastInsertId + ",  @"  + members.childTextBoxes[i].Key + ")", members.DBConnection))
     {
         members.DBCommand.Parameters.AddWithValue("@" + members.childTextBoxes[i].Key, members.childTextBoxes[i].Value);
     }
         // error occurs here. i'm assuming its to do 
         if (members.DBCommand.ExecuteNonQuery() > 0)
         {
              MessageBox.Show("Records inserted", "QBC", MessageBoxButtons.OK);
         }
    } 
}
```

I hope this is enough information that describes the problem I am confused about.

Any help would be appreciated.

Thanks!

I can try to add more information if it helps make my question more clear.

update-

I went ahead and tried to use .Add instead of .AddWithValue but unfortunately that kept giving me an insert into query syntax error.

Here is the updated code for the insert query builder:

```
 string fieldList = $"{string.Join(",", members.childTextBoxes.Select(tb => mapToDatabase[tb.Key]))}";
 string valueList = $"{string.Join(",", members.childTextBoxes.Select(tb => "?"))}";

 string insertQuery = $"INSERT INTO children {fieldList} VALUES {valueList}";

 using (members.DBCommand = new System.Data.OleDb.OleDbCommand(insertQuery, members.DBConnection))
 { 
     foreach (var field in members.childTextBoxes)
     {
         members.DBCommand.Parameters.Add("@" + field.Key, OleDbType.LongVarChar).Value = field.Value;
     }


     if (members.DBCommand.ExecuteNonQuery() > 0) // error occurs here
     {
         MessageBox.Show("Records inserted", "QBC", MessageBoxButtons.OK);
     }
 }
```

Comment: Your `INSERT` statement is hard coded to accept exactly 4 parameters (with *very* specific names).  If you want to build this truly dynamically, you will need some method of generating a field list to match the values list that you are creating.  You can *probably* do that with the key from your dictionary, as long as the field names in the database exactly match the names of the controls.

Comment: unfortunately they don't, and there are twenty textboxes I need to go through, I have it so it only gets the ones that are not empty and adds it to the list. Is there a way to rename dynamically the textboxes names or something else to match the database columns?

Comment: You would be better off using a `Dictionary<string, string>` to map control names to field names, where the key is the control name, and the value is the field name it maps to.

Comment: I'm sorry, I am really new (just started using c# from PHP). How exactly would I go about doing that? Like would it be `Dictionary<string, string>(textBoxChildName1.Name, "childName");`? If that is the case, would I have to do that for each 20? Right now I am assigning all the non empty values to `members.childTextBoxes` list. and also, wouldn't `@" + members.childTextBoxes[i].Key + ")"` as the bound parameter and then assigning the parameter with `members.DbCommand.Parameters.AddWithValue("@" + members.childTextBoxes[i].Key, members.ChildTextBoxes[i].Value)` do that?

Comment: because I did something similar and the database columns were not the same name as the textbox controls

Comment: You are close. The mapping dictionary would be hard coded. You would do something like `var controlMap = new Dictionary<string, string>();`.  And you would add each control to it with `controlMap.Add("textBoxChildName1","childName")`.  Then when you find a control, you can just look up its name in the dictionary, and you will know what the field name is for it.

Comment: I also just noticed that you are using parameters in the form of "@paramName" with an `OleDbCcommand`, that may not work reliably.  That form is for use with Microsoft SQL Server.  The `OleDbCommand` format is using an unnamed "?" to represent a parameters, and they are applied in the order they are added. See [MSDN](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.data.oledb.oledbcommand.parameters(v=vs.110).aspx)

Comment: would it be `controlMap.add(textBoxChildName1.Name, "childName")` or just the name in double quotes

Comment: You could do it either way.  Your way might actually be a little safer, since if you end up renaming a control, you would know as soon as you tried to compile, where as with the literal string (double quotes), you would only find out later.

Comment: sorry, one more question, how would that work with adding it to the values or the parameters. Like `mapToDatabase.Add(textBoxChild1.Name, "childName");
                                mapToDatabase.Add(textBoxChild1Birthday.Name, "birthday");
                                mapToDatabase.Add(textBoxChild1Email.Name, "childEmail");` how or where would I do that for the insert query? under `members.DBCommand.Parameters.AddWithValue(what here, what here)`. Sorry, I'm just really confused.

Comment: Typing up some example code in an answer for you.

Answer (score 0):

The best I can tell from the code you are showing in your question, you would want something like this:

```
var controlMap = new Dictionary<string, string>();
controlMap.Add(nameof(txtChildName), "ChildName");
controlMap.Add(nameof(txtParentName), "ParentName");

string fieldList = $"({string.Join(",", childTextBoxes.Select(tb => controlMap[tb.Key]))})" ;
string valueList = $"({string.Join(",", childTextBoxes.Select(tb => "?"))})";
string insertStatement = $"INSERT INTO children {fieldList} VALUES {valueList}";

var command = new OleDbCommand(insertStatement, members.DBConnection);
foreach (var field in childTextBoxes)
{
    command.Parameters.Add(field.Value);
}
```

[`OleDbCommand`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.data.oledb.oledbcommand.parameters(v=vs.110).aspx) doesn't support named parameters, so you have to use positional ones.  They are marked with an "?", and added in the order they are used.

You also need to build both the field list, and the values list in the SQL insert statement, so that that order of fields in your field list matches the order that the "?" markers will be populated when you add the parameters.

I haven't been able to test this, since I don't have your full setup, but it should get you pretty close.  It assumes that `childTextBoxes` is declared as `List<KeyValuePair<string, string>>` since I can't see your actual declaration.  You may have to adjust that a bit if it isn't correct.

Comment: yes child text boxes is a key value pair (`public List<KeyValuePair<string, string>> childTextBoxes = new List<KeyValuePair<string, string>>();`) sorry, was defined in another file.

Comment: I'm getting an error of `System.InvalidCastException: 'The OleDbParameterCollection only accepts non-null OleDbParameter type objects, not String objects.` under
 `foreach (var field in members.childTextBoxes)
  {
        members.DBCommand.Parameters.Add(field.Value);
  }`

Comment: Looks like that needs to be wrapped in an `OleDbParameter`. You should be able to find something by searching on that. If not, I can help more in the morning, I need to get some sleep now.

Comment: tried this:

`foreach (var field in members.childTextBoxes)
                                    {
                                        members.DBCommand.Parameters.Add(new System.Data.OleDb.OleDbParameter("?", field.Value));
                                    }` 

but getting a error saying `Syntax error in INSERT INTO statement.` :/

Comment: I've tried other things but I can't get it to work. Could you provide an example?

Comment: it's getting the textbox columns in the reverse order, i wonder if that is why it is throwing a insert into query syntax error?

Answer (score 0):

fixed the error, I had to enclose the insert values with parenthesis.
 `string insertQuery = $"INSERT INTO children (pid, {fieldList}) VALUES (?,{valueList})";`

that fixed it.